# SELECT Statement from YAML used in Java input returns empty resultset from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, select, yaml

I have the following YAML specification for a JAR I am using. The YML is input for a JAR I don't have control, it's a black-box for me. My DEV has tested the very same input SELECT against his Oracle database and it works fine.

When I execute it on my customer database though, I always get an empty resultset. The query returns the fieldnames, but no records.
I have checked via SQLPlus, and the connection is valid, SQL correct. I only have this issue accessing the database via JDBC / that JAR application. Java version is 17 and Oracle 19c. The Oracle is hosted on a remote host, not local. DEV has the same architecture. Only "minor" difference is, that the DEV has executed the code against ORA 21. However, I would not expect that a simple SELECT statement like mine should have any Oracle Release incompatibilities.

Any ideas, what could be wrong?

```yaml
datasources: 
   - name: dlpview
     uri: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@customer-connection-string:port:sid"
     username: myuser
     password: mypasswd

routes:
   - name: IBAN
     batch-size: 100
     batch-time: 100
     max-idle-time: 360
     input:
         type: SELECT
         datasource: dlpview
         statement: "SELECT * FROM k.abc$dlp_view"
     output:
         type: CSV
         file:
             path: c:/mytemp
             name: output.csv
         csv:
             line-separator: "\r\n"
             field-separator: "\"
```

We already tried several different kind of SELECTs, removed the entire Camel component, which originally was inside the Java code to make sure, Camel is not interfering. We also tried several escaping of the select statement.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, there are two separate databases (dev and customer)? Maybe a stupid question, but do these databases contain the same data?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. No , by DEV I mean my Developer who has the code under control. I am on the integration project and can only modify the yaml.

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` the data? If the data is not `COMMIT`ted then it is only visible in the session where it was `INSERT`ed. It is only once it has been `COMMIT`ted that all users can see it.

Comment: I only read data from the view. The data is source data for my dlp sytem from the customers CRM system, and with other selects I assured that there is data using the very same connection string and sql select statement. Only if I use this yaml construct and the JAR provided I get empty resultsets.